# Images didnt load on masterslider in any responsive device mobile and Ipad

Tags: image, mobile, load

I am using Master Slider In my Wordpress site.When resize browser window manually slider is working fine but when I test it with my mobile images didnt load generally, I only see loader image.I tried to be sure that all divs are streched with their parent and all is ok but images didnt load on mobile devices.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.It was because of other jquery library of slider, so they are getting on conflict with each other.